# python filename clean up

Tags: python, regex

In python is it possible to strip off all special characters and spaces and replace with hyphen but retain dot extensions (i.e. file extension such as .mp4 or .mov or .txt or .jpg or .png or .pdf)

For example:

```
string = 'Special $#! characters   spaces_ 888323.mp4'
```

should result in

```
Special-characters-spaces_-888323.mp4
```

I am using the following method but don't think its a right way

```
re.sub('(\W+)','-', string).replace('-mp4','.mp4').replace('-mov','.mov')
```

Comment: Technically, anything that works is the right way. However, there are better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really file names you're dealing with, consider using [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to temporarily detach the extension:

```
name, ext = os.path.splitext(string)
```

Now you can freely operate on `name`, keeping `ext` intact:

```
name = re.sub('(\W+)','-', name)
```

And then you just recombine:

```
string = name + ext
```

If it bothers you that this isn't a one-liner, make it into a function. I would also recommend pre-compiling the regex.

Comment: Oh nice, you added a splitext solution as well ;-) So I'm deleting mine, this is better.

Comment: Whoops. I'm on mobile so seeing everything delayed. Didn't see your update until you mentioned it.

Comment: It did not occur to me that the split + join nonsense I was doing could in fact become a simple sub just by adding a capture group... I am a doob and I need some sleep.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. I rather liked your answer. Thanks for the vote of confidence though.